# Unable to fetch the div style left value....

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning javascript and I was trying to move a div element using javascript. I was using the left and top property of style to move the div. The code is below.

```
html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
window.onload = function() {

    divObj = document.getElementById('divObj');

    window.onkeydown=function(e) {
        var keycode;
        keycode = e.keyCode;
        speed = 1;
        if(keycode == 37) {        
           divObj.style.left = (parseInt(divObj.style.left) - speed) + "px"; }
        else if(keycode == 38)
           divObj.style.top = (parseInt(divObj.style.top) - speed) + "px";
        else if(keycode == 39)
           divObj.style.left = (parseInt(divObj.style.left) + speed) + "px";  
        else if(keycode == 40)
           divObj.style.top = (parseInt(divObj.style.top) + speed) - "px";    

        }
    }
</script>

<style>
div.div1 { width : 200px;
          height :50px;
          background-color : #333;
          position:absolute;
          left:0px;
          top:0px;
        }
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id = "divObj" class = "div1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the 'divObj.style.left' is not returning any value and so the div cannot be moved using the up and down key.

If anyone knows how to get the values of style left property of the div, please let me know.

Comment: If you haven't _set_ the `style.left` before, it'll be `''`, (CSS rule in a stylesheet doesn't affect the value of `style.left/top` properties.) You could try `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` properties instead of styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need individual braces for all your else if statements

```
if(keycode == 37) {        
           divObj.style.left = (parseInt(divObj.style.left) - speed) + "px"; }
        else if(keycode == 38){
           divObj.style.top = (parseInt(divObj.style.top) - speed) + "px";}
        else if(keycode == 39){
           divObj.style.left = (parseInt(divObj.style.left) + speed) + "px"; } 
        else if(keycode == 40){
           divObj.style.top = (parseInt(divObj.style.top) + speed) - "px";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.onload = function () {
divObj = document.getElementById('divObj');

window.onkeydown = function (e) {
   var keycode;
   keycode = e.keyCode;
   speed = 1;
   if (keycode == 37)
      divObj.style.left = 
           ((divObj.style.left == "" ? "0" : parseInt(divObj.style.left)) + speed) + "px";
   else if (keycode == 38)
       divObj.style.top = 
           ((divObj.style.top == "" ? "0" : parseInt(divObj.style.top)) + speed) + "px";
   else if (keycode == 39)
        divObj.style.left = (
           (divObj.style.left == "" ? "0" : parseInt(divObj.style.left)) + speed) + "px";
   else if (keycode == 40)
        divObj.style.top = 
            ((divObj.style.top == "" ? "0" : parseInt(divObj.style.top)) + speed) + "px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it this way

```
divObj = document.getElementById('divObj');

 window.onkeydown=function(e) {
        var keycode;
        var lll = divObj.offsetLeft
        var rrr = divObj.offsetTop
        keycode = e.keyCode;
        speed = 1;
        if(keycode == 37) {        

           divObj.style.left = lll - speed+"px";}

        else if(keycode == 38){
          divObj.style.top = rrr - speed+"px";}
        else if(keycode == 39){
           divObj.style.left = lll + speed+"px";}
        else if(keycode == 40){
          divObj.style.top = rrr + speed+"px";}
 }
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NU7N5/4/)**

Comment: hey, thank you so much.. That was very helpful.. Its working now. Thanks.